# Scala program for validating a binary search tree

Tags: algorithm, scala, data-structures

I am having some errors in running the code for binary search tree validation using recursion. Can anyone have a look into the method and confirm if it is a optimized method for validation?

I also need some inputs for resolving errors below.

error: identifier expected but 'val found, illegal start of expression.

```
object Solution {

    def isValidBST(root: TreeNode): Boolean = {
    if (root == null) true
    isValidBST(root.left, Double.MAX_VALUE, root.val) &&
    isValidBST(root.right, root.val, Double.MAX_VALUE)
  }

  private def isValidBST(node: TreeNode, min: Double, max: Double): Boolean = {
    if (node == null) true
    if (node.val <= min || node.val >= max) false
    isValidBST(node.left, min, node.val) && isValidBST(node.right,node.val, max)

  }


}
```

Comment: Please try and create a [mcve]

Comment: -1 because not only you did not address my comments on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60516111/for-a-binary-search-tree-i-need-to-compute-the-length-of-the-diameter-of-the-tre#comment107059988_60516111) but also created this question that has the same issues which makes it really confusing for people trying to help with the algorithm implementation because of numerous basic issues with the usage of Scala language.

Answer (score 1):

1. `val` is a reserved word. You can't use it as a variable, or data member, name.
2. It's `Double.MaxValue`, not `Double.MAX_VALUE`.
3. Your recursion has no exit path because your `if` expressions have no `else` clause.